# How to put ballon (point) to Google Maps App

Tags: react-native, google-maps

What do I need:

Open google maps application from my ReactNative app with a point on certain coordinates. And show a balloon (ideally with some information inside)

I've checked both  [Google Maps Intents for Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents) and [Google Maps URL Scheme for iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/ios-urlscheme) but don't see any param responsible for that.

Does anyone know how to solve the moment?

Comment: the params can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide). see example number 3 for the use of gps coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to do that with combining `center` (to put map center) and `q` (with same coordinates as in center)

```html
comgooglemaps://?center=59.515383,24.652798&q=59.515383,24.652798


geo://?center=59.515383,24.652798&q=59.515383,24.652798
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not change marker  in Google Maps Intents.
if you want to show custom marker you have to use google maps api in Application and draw you own layer over the map.

if you want to use google map api in react native use [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps)  it provide native map components.